# React with REST API - State or GET on mount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

We're currently building a React-Redux frontend with a REST API backend powered by Node. I'm unsure about whether to use a Redux or a simple call to the API on mounting the component.

The component is a simple list of profiles which are going to be displayed throughout (but not constantly) the site.

Sorry for asking this. Maybe there's something to read through available?

Comment: It's a better approach of using redux. But you have to make sure that that your reactjs components doesn't operate on data directly, it should be just an html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to take a look at two things:

1) The first React tutorial on Facebook is very underrated:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

It exposes a very clear way to think about how to think about the tree structure of your views.

2) From there, move to reading about Containers and Components:
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

This post explains that React components too often do two things: act as renderers and as controllers (taking on both the V and the C on MVC).

Now, what your React view needs is a controller. Fetching it whenever you mount the component overlaps two different concerns: how to display the information and how to fetch it.

You could do it with a single, bigger React component that manages the complete state of your application:

```es2016
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/profiles').then(res => res.json().then(::this.setState))
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state) {
      return <ProfileList profiles={this.state} />
    } else {
      return <span>Loading...</span>
    }
  }
}
```

That would be your "Container". Your "Component" is a pure representation of the list of profiles, that needs not care about how that information was retrieved:

```es2016
class ProfileList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ul>
      {
        this.props.profiles.map(
          profile => <li key={profile.id}>{profile.name}</li>
        )
      }
    </ul>
  }
}
```

Redux is just another way of doing this that enables better reuse of information, and makes that same information available to different components (hiding the instance of the "store" as a mixin). That `MyApp` class on top of your structure serves a similar function to the `Provider` class in redux: allowing child components to access information needed to display themselves.